# How can I use (reflection?) to make reusable code for populating object with xml data

Tags: vb.net, linq, reflection

I'm using VB.NET 2013 and am trying to write an application that will import (from csv file) customer contact information (for example: CustomerName, ContactLast, ContactFirst, ContactPhn, ContactEmail).  There are going to be multiple csv layouts that have to be dealt with, so I'm using an XML file to store the various mappings in.

I'd like to load the defined maps from DataMaps.xlm into DataMap objects then insert those DataMap objects into a list box.  I'd like to have them populated with the XML values before I load them into the listbox.  I don't expect that there will ever be more than 10 - 15 defined maps, so loading them right away shouldn't be much of a problem with memory or speed (as it will be a locally run application with locally stored xml data).

***What I have so far:***

### **Contact Object** (short and sweet for this example - not really needed at this point, but given so you can see how the data map is used)

```
Private mCompany as String
Private mLastName as String
Private mFirstName as String
Private mPhone as String
Private mEmail As String
```

<... Support Get/Set items (Properties are same as private variables; minus the leading "m") ...>

### **DataMap Object** (short and sweet again for this example)

```
Private mDataMapName as String
private mCompany_Col as Integer
private mLastName_Col as Integer
private mFirstName_Col as Integer
private mPhone_Col As Integer
private mEmail_Col As String
```

<... Support Get/Set items (Properties are same as private variables; minus the leading "m") ...>

### "**Standard**" CSV layout

"Company ABC", "Jones", "June", "515-874-0098", "JJ@ABC.COM"

"Company EFG", "Williams", "Alan", "515-874-2887", "alan@efg.com"

The DataMap for this layout would be:

```
<Map>
    <DataMapName>Standard</DataMapName>
    <Company>1</Company>
    <LastName>2</LastName>
    <FirstName>3</FirstName>
    <Phone>4</Phone>
    <Email>5</Email>
</Map>
```

### "**Not Standard 01**" CSV Layout

"Jones", "June", "Company ABC", "515-874-0098", "JJ@ABC.COM"

"Williams", "Alan" "Company EFG", "515-874-2887", "alan@efg.com"

The DataMap for this format would be:

```
<Map>
    <DataMapName>Not Standard 01</DataMapName>
    <Company>3</Company>
    <LastName>1</LastName>
    <FirstName>2</FirstName>
    <Phone>4</Phone>
    <Email>5</Email>
</Map>
```

I'm just picking up VB.NET again and am not comfortable with determining the "best" techniques to use while reading data from the .xml file (I can retrieve a list of s using LINQ currently) and populating my DataMap object.  I know I can do it by using each individual property to set the values; but I'd like to write generic (looping) code as this app may be rewritten with changes to the DataMap requirements as well as using this in other application instances.

Currently, I am able to create a new  element and add it to the DataMaps.xml file.  I can then read those changes correctly.

Where I'm stuck is writing a 'generic' populateMap(mapName As String) function.  Where I am right now, I can get the map (as an Enumeration of XElement) and then individually look at each property and store it into a new instance of a DataMap object:

```
Dim dm as New DataMap
dm.DataMapName = map.Element("DataMapName").Value
dm.Company_Col = map.Element("Company_Col").value
dm.LastName_Col = map.Element("LastName_Col").value
dm.FirstName_Col = map.Element("FirstName_Col").value
```

...

But, I'd like know if it's possible to create something like: (pseudocode)

```
Dim dm As new DataMap
Dim myInstance As New DataMap
Dim myFields As FieldInfo()
Dim myType As Type = GetType(DataMap)

try 
    myFields = myType.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    for each element in map.Elements
            Dim f as FieldInfo = GETType(DataMap).GetField(field.name)
        dm.(some sort of reference to a FieldInfo() column name, or something) = element.f
        (this would look like: dm.Company_Col = element.Company_Col (or a variable referencing the private value "mCompany_Col")
    next
catch ...
Finally ...
End Try
```

Comment: your map just needs to store the data order of the source files such as {"Company", "Email", "Foo", "Bar"}, stored in a List or maybe a Dictionary.  Then a SELECT CASE statement to iterate the collection and map them.  `Case "Company" // myThing.Company = csvValue`.  Seems like the tail is wagging the dog.

Comment: I can get the values from the map.Element("<property name>").Value and set them 1by1.  I'm hoping the group also finds out that they'll need an import for the vendors as well as customers (from an old ERP system and spreadsheets).  I can then basically reuse the 'generic' block of code (variable variable in php as I called it) code without having to rewrite the SELECT statement for a new set of <Map> values.  Just trying to find a way to reuse this process of populating objects in other instances of XML.

Sorry if I misunderstand your help.  I'm always looking for better ways.

Comment: the case statement would be the same  for all maps related to this object (inside a loop iterating the collection): when "Company" comes up - whenever it comes up, 1st, 3rd, last - you know what you are working with.  The column tags would just be in the collection in a different order. The maps might be stored elsewhere, XML or DB.